# Returning BadRequest in ASP.Net Core MVC to Microsoft jQuery Unobtrusive Ajax post has ModelState undefined

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-core-mvc, unobtrusive-ajax

**THE PROBLEM**

I am trying to return service side validation errors from ModelState using BadRequest(ModelState) but when I try to assign the the jQuery ModelState from xhr.responseText I am getting undefined error in javascript. I am using ASP.Net Core 1.0.1 with Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax 3.2.3.

**THE CODE**

*Controller Action*

```
public async Task<IActionResult> ApplySanction(SanctionViewModel model)
{
    try
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //update database
            return RedirectToAction("Details");
        }
        else
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return StatusCode(500, ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

*View (JavaScript)*

```
function AjaxOnFailure(xhr, status, error) {
    console.log(xhr.responseText);

    var errText = "";
    var response = null;
    var errors = [];
    var errorsString = "";
    if (xhr.status == 400) {
        try {
            response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            console.log(response);
        }
        catch (e) {
            errText = "Error: " + xhr.status + " - " + error;
        }
    }
    if (response != null) {
        var modelState = response.ModelState; //This is returning undefined
        console.log(modelState);
        for (var key in modelState) {
            if (modelState.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                for (var i = 0; i < modelState[key].length; i++) {
                    errorsString = (errorsString == "" ? "" : errorsString + "<br/>") + modelState[key][i];
                    errors.push(modelState[key][i]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (errorsString != "") { 
        errText = "Validation Error: " + errorsString;
    } 

    console.log(errText);
    var errIcon = "fa fa-exclamation-circle"
    document.getElementById("modalErrorIcon").className = errIcon;
    document.getElementById("modalErrorText").innerHTML = errText;
}
```

*View (Form)*

```
<form asp-controller="Client" asp-action="ApplySanction" class="form-horizontal" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="POST" data-ajax-success="CloseModal(xhr, status, '#sanctionModal')" data-ajax-failure="AjaxOnFailure(xhr, status, error)">
    <div class="modal fade" id="sanctionModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="sanctionModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="sanctionModalLabel">Sanction Reason</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <input type="hidden" asp-for="ID" />
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <textarea asp-for="SanctionReason" class="form-control" autofocus></textarea>
                            <span asp-validation-for="SanctionReason" class="text-danger" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <div class="text-danger pull-left">
                        <i id="modalErrorIcon" class=""></i>
                        <span id="modalErrorText"></span>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**THE RESULTS**

[Javascript Debug Session](https://i.stack.imgur.com/00qeb.png)

[Console Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZMt7.png)

**THE QUESTIONS**

1. Why is my ModelState undefined in my ajax response?
2. What is the point of using javascript to show validation errors after server side validation? I ask this because I would assume my server side validation only kicks in if a user has javascript disabled on hence client side validation is bypassed. Therefore how can the javascript execute to show the validation errors return by the server ModelState since it's still disabled?

Comment: your ModelState  is undefined  because you don't return it from the server, see the value of response

Comment: @madalinivascu I don't understand what you mean. Doesn't this line in my controller return the ModelState from the server `return BadRequest(ModelState);`? I can see the correct server validation error being returned from the server (see Console Log image) in what appears to be the correct json format too.

Comment: where do you see in Console Log image the object property `ModelState` i only see a array id with the first item value `The value '' is invalid`

Comment: @madalinivascu I see what you mean now so I've added the form code for clarity. There's a hidden input field `<input type="hidden" asp-for="ID" />` which is null when hitting the server. The ModelState array returned from the server has the key ID with matching message `The value '' is invalid`. I have based my js code on this example [link](https://forums.asp.net/t/2016501.aspx?Extract+ModelState+error+messages+in+jQuery) which suggests that with jquery a ModelState object can be extracted from doing `JSON.parse(xhr.responseText)`. Perhaps this is not compatible with jquery unobtrusive ajax?

Comment: it seems your current syntax doesn't return a a key value pair only the value of ModelState

Comment: this has nothing to do with ajax or javascript (never heard of unobtrusive ajax ) this more like a ajax return format issue

Comment: @madalinivascu thanks for your help. i believe you are correct and although i couldn't find a successful way to return the key/value pairs of ModelState i just went with displaying the values only and not worrying about showing the keys too. i can't see where to upvote your comment but if you want to repost as answer i will mark it as answered accordingly.

Comment: glad to have helped lol that was 2 weeks ago :)

Comment: @OjM - Can you post the code you used to display the values without the keys? I'm having a similar issue.

Comment: @RyanBuening sorry for such late reply but I can't really help anymore because I got rid of way of doing things and deleted that section of code. It just didn't seem right because if the form failed javascript validation then there is no point using javascript to try and display the error messages.